# How to split passed ListView item in another intent?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I'm new to android and java, I work on this android project, where I have a `ListView` of Movies (Name-String, Genre-String, Year-Int). I want to split the Item after I've passed it to another `activity`.

My Movie Model:

```
public class Movie
{
    // property to help us handle the data
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private int year;


    //Getters and Setters of the properties
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre)
    {
        this.genre = genre;
    }


    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return name + ", " + genre + ", " + year;
    }



//----------Start--------- Here we have defined the table contents (basically a blueprint of the table Movie) -------------------------------------

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "movie";
    public static final String COlUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COlUMN_NAME = "make";
    public static final String COlUMN_GENRE = "model";
    public static final String COlUMN_YEAR = "year";

//----------------------END----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

}
```

My Create Movie Activity:

```
 public class CreateMovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    MoviesRepository moviesRepository;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_movie);

        moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(this);
        moviesRepository.open();
    }

    public void onClickSaveMovie(View v)
    {
        Button buttonAdd = (Button) v;

        EditText editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        EditText editTextGenre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextGenre);
        EditText editTextYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextYear);

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName(editTextName.getText().toString());
        movie.setGenre(editTextGenre.getText().toString());
        movie.setYear(Integer.parseInt(editTextYear.getText().toString()));


        moviesRepository.Create(movie);


        Button buttonCreate = (Button) v;
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }

}
```

My Movie Repository:

```
public class MoviesRepository
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private MyDBHelper myDBHelper;


    private String [] MovieAllColumns ={Movie.COlUMN_ID,
            Movie.COlUMN_NAME,
            Movie.COlUMN_GENRE,
            Movie.COlUMN_YEAR};



    public MoviesRepository(Context context)
    {
        myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(context);
    }


    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
        //Open connection to write data
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void close()
    {
        //Close connection to database
        db.close();
    }

    private Movie cursorToMovie (Cursor cursor)
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        movie.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        movie.setGenre(cursor.getString(2));
        movie.setYear(cursor.getInt(3));

        return movie;
    }

    public List<Movie> getAllMovies()
    {
        open();

        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Movie.TABLE_NAME, MovieAllColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Movie movie = cursorToMovie(cursor);
            movieList.add(movie);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        close();
        return movieList;

    }



    public void Create(Movie movie)
    {
        open();

        //helps you insert values to the table
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //Put method - first column; what column do you want to be storing this ind. Second; what is the value you want to put ind
        values.put(Movie.COlUMN_NAME, movie.getName());
        values.put(Movie.COlUMN_GENRE, movie.getGenre());
        values.put(Movie.COlUMN_YEAR, movie.getYear());

        db.insert(Movie.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        close();
    }


    public void Delete(Movie movie)
    {
        open();
        //Deletes Movie by id
        db.delete(Movie.TABLE_NAME, Movie.COlUMN_ID + " = " + movie.getId(), null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

When I click on an item on the `ListView` it will pass the value to another `Activity` where I'm able to print it out (make toast).

This is where I pass the item to the other intent:

```
 public void Select()
    {
        moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(this);
        moviesRepository.open();

        final Movie movie;

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMovie);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                final String details = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("key", details);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
```

But how do I split the passed value from the `ListView`, so that it makes sense.

This is where I want to split it in three values, Movie Name, Movie Genre and Year:

```
public class MovieDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView movieName;
    TextView movieGenre;
    TextView movieYear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_details);
        getDetails();
    }
    public void getDetails()
    {
        movieName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieName);
        movieGenre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieGenre);
        movieYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieYear);

        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");


        Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

Right now I'm just making a toast with the passed item

Answer (score 0):

Create a `moviemanager` class which is singleton and has a `map`. Save your movies as `<String, Movie>` into the map. Then you can call `Moviemanager.getInstance().getMovie(key)` to get the movie object.

Comment: I figured it out, but I wonder how I can pass data from the database (SqlLite) to the other intent. Or How can I compare the send string object with the data in my database? So that I can get all the columns for that row.

Comment: As i said you create a manager class for this. You have to init this manager with the data from your database. Then you can send the key from your activity to another one like you did. In your second activity you can ask the manager to get the right movie for the passed key. Your manager and your database have the same data at this time. That's the way i did in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to split the String you receive in the details screen.

It's quite simple actually ;-)

In your `MovieDetailsActivity#getDetails` when you've gotten the details String from the `Intent`, you need to do the following:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
String[] splitMovieString = data.split(", ");
```

Then you can set your `TextView`s like so:

```
movieName.setText(splitMovieString[0]);
movieGenre.setText(splitMovieString[1]);
movieYear.setText(splitMovieString[2]);
```

**On a side-note:**

Your approach with sending the data as a String through the `Intent` is OK, but it is not the preferred way in Android to pass data between Activities.

There is a way to pass the whole `Movie` object, but only if you change your object to implement the `Parcelable` interface. (See [the official documentation for a full example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html))

After implementing `Parcelable` your `Movie` object will look like this:

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private int year;

    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        genre = in.readString();
        year = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movie(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(id);
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(genre);
        parcel.writeInt(year);
    }

   [... Setters, getters and your constants are removed for brevity]
}
```

Now after you've changed your model a bit, you can pass it directly through the `Intent` system like this:

In your `Select` method inside the `OnClickListener` you'll need to change your `Intent` a bit:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final Movie selectedMovie = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieDetailsActivity.class);
    detailsIntent.putExtra(Movie.class.getName(), selectedMovie);
    startActivity(detailsIntent);
}
```

What's happening here is that we basically "flatten" (or serialize) the `Movie` object into an object that can be sent through the `Intent` system.
Now when you receive the `Intent` in your `MovieDetailsActivity#getDetails`, you need to unwrap (or deserialize) your "flattened" `Movie` object again so you can use it like a normal `Movie` object.

So now your `MovieDetailsActivity#getDetails` should look like this:

```
public void getDetails() {
    movieName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieName);
    movieGenre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieGenre);
    movieYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieYear);

    Movie movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Movie.class.getName());
    // Now you can set your movie name, genre and year directly from your object.
    movieName.setText(movie.getName());
    movieGenre.setText(movie.getGenre());
    movieYear.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getYear()); // Notice you cannot set an Integer directly as the text of a `TextView`, you need to parse it as a String first.
}
```

I know this last solution will bring more code to your classes, but it is really the best way of doing this and when you make your model classes implement the `Parcelable` interface Android Studio will tell you that you're missing the implementation and actually ask you if you need help with implementing the `Parcelable`, so you don't really have to do much on your own.

As a final note there's another solution and that is to just pass the `id` of the current `Movie` through the `Intent` and then fetch from your `MoviesRepository` directly in the `MovieDetailsActivity`, but then you would also have to extend your `MoviesRepository` with a new method that could fetch a single `Movie` from your repo.

I know it's a long answer, but there are many concepts to take care of here :-)